# Case not returning rows

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, case

The following code is a front end parameter - Quantity but when the user enters '0' it is not returning any rows (there are). Is there something wrong here or to add something?     This is used in Crystal Reports. This is part of the 'Record Select'

```
(Select {?Quantity}
    CASE "ALL":
        1=1
    CASE "Negative":
        ({ACBALMPK.IRQOH#}<0) OR ({ACBALMPK.IEQOH#}<0)
    CASE "Zero":
        ({ACBALMPK.IRQOH#}=0) OR ({ACBALMPK.IEQOH#}=0)
    CASE "Greater than Zero":
        ({ACBALMPK.IRQOH#}>0;) OR ({ACBALMPK.IEQOH#}>0;))
```

Comment: What variant of SQL is this? The query you're showing looks like it should trigger an error in most dialects I know.

Comment: It's used in Crystal Reports for record select. I didn't write it but have to modify.

Comment: Is the user actually entering '0' as mentioned, or is it "Zero" being entered? (Or is the parameter itself doing it: Value="Zero", Description="0".)  There is no default setting, so any parameter value other than "ALL", "Negative", "Zero", or "Greater than Zero" will return no records.  If that is not it, I suspect something else in the record select. By the way, your code worked fine in my data (using different field names).